# memory problems with imageMagick?

Tags: windows, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, hard-drive, color-palette

I have problems using `convert F:\path\source.png -define registry:temporary-path=F:\path -limit area 0 -type palette -colors 256 F:\path\target.png`

the temporary-path and my source and target images are on an external hard drive. I used area 0 because I don't want ImageMagick to use my systems memory or C:.

The error(s) I am getting:

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `F:\path\target.png': File exists @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
```

and

```
convert.exe: WriteBlob Failed `F:\path\target.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1645.
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `-define reg...`, does it work then? What happens if you remove the `-limit...`, does it work then? What happens if you use an inout file in the current directory, does it work then? What happens if you use and output file in the current directory, does it work then? You are going to have to narrow it down to find what the problem is - though I will guess it is spaces or quoting file paths.

Comment: I left out just `-define reg..` and than just `-limit...` and than both of them but the same errors.. I find that strange. 
I should mention that source.png is HUGE (bigger than 40k x 20k pixels). But I have around 120 GiB space at F:\

Comment: Is your F:| drive FAT32 or NTFS?

Comment: And are you running 64-bit Windows to process such monsters?

Comment: F: drive ist NTFS (HDD) and I have a I7 with an SSD and 8GB Ram. My Windows 7 is 64-bit. Is it possible to "overwrite" the the source png with the target png. I mean: Can they have the same name?

Comment: It is normally possible, but the error message implies that is the problem. Strange! What version of IM are you running?

Comment: I run ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8 . I went to F:\path and ran `convert -type palette -colors 256 source.png` and it worked. Now I will try that from C:\ and with `-define...`

Comment: yeah that worked, thanks! Maybe you could post that as an answer so I this question is marked as answered.

Comment: Great! Which part actually made the difference in the end?

Comment: I used `convert -define registry:temporary-path=F:\path -type palette -colors 256 F:\path\source.png` So I removed -limit 0 (I don't know whether THAT was really the problem or not) And I didn't specify a different outputfile. So the inputfile gets changed but that is ok for me.

Comment: @MarkSetchell won't you post an answer so that I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some general advice really on dealing with problems with ImageMagick and large images.

1. If you are dealing with images that are tens of thousands of rows by tens of thousands of columns, that can pretty soon mount up and exceed the limits of a 32-bit OS and ImageMagick binary, so make sure you are running 64-bit.
2. Beware of seeing that you have a 130GB filesystem, and assuming that means you can write a 130GB file, since FAT filesystems are limited to no individual file exceeding 2GB (FAT16) or 4GB (FAT32) and that includes any `intermediate working files`.
3. Start simple, if your command doesn't work, trim it down to the absolute minimum till it does work, then build it back up until you see what is causing the problems, so I would recommend removing your `-limit` and your `-define` initially until it works and then add them back in, one at a time.

Good luck.